# Bool not returning true in IF statement C# Unity

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, boolean, instantiation

```
GameObject ZombieCard1, ZombieCard2, ZombieCard3, ZombieCard4, ZombieCard5;
int randomnumberpicker;
public static bool leftChoice, rightChoice;
void Start()
{

    statusBars = FindObjectOfType<StatusBars>();
}


void Update()
{
    ZombieCards();

}

void ZombieCards()
{
    if (GameObject.FindWithTag("Card") == null)
    { 
     randomnumberpicker = Random.Range(1, 5);
     Debug.Log(randomnumberpicker);
     if(randomnumberpicker == 1)
        {
           ZombieCard1 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Frontcard1")) as GameObject;
           ZombieCard1.transform.Translate(0, -1, 0);
            if (leftChoice == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Jesus Marty! you fixed it! Great Scott!");
            }
        }
     else if(randomnumberpicker == 2)
        {
            ZombieCard2 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Frontcard2")) as GameObject;
            ZombieCard2.transform.Translate(0, -1, 0);
        }
     else if (randomnumberpicker == 3)
        {
            ZombieCard3 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Frontcard3")) as GameObject;
            ZombieCard3.transform.Translate(0, -1, 0);
        }
     else if (randomnumberpicker == 4)
        {
            ZombieCard4 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Frontcard4")) as GameObject;
            ZombieCard4.transform.Translate(0, -1, 0);
        }
     else if (randomnumberpicker == 5)
        {
            ZombieCard5 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Frontcard5")) as GameObject;
            ZombieCard5.transform.Translate(0, -1, 0);
        }
    }
}
 void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("LeftArrow"))
        {
            leftChoice = true;
            Debug.Log("Left arrow is working");
            return;
        }
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("RightArrow"))
        {
            rightChoice = true;
            Debug.Log("Right arrow is working");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I posted this earlier but due to lack of clarity (on my part) I can't figure out why this if statement

```
if (leftChoice == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Jesus Marty! you fixed it! Great Scott!");
        }
```

isn't executing, the bool is being set to true on mousedown correct?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can be very sure that if `leftChoice` is `true`, you'll enter on the whole `if` block...

Comment: Wouldn't `ZombieCards()` get called before you have a chance to trigger `OnMouseDown()`, causing it to instantiate a card (which I presume would create an object with tag "Card") and result in it never entering that initial if statement in `ZombieCards()` again? Please describe the sequence of events that you want to happen, because I think you may have a logical error in your code.

Comment: Just curious. Where and when do you set those global static variables back to false?

Comment: @Serlite I want the bool to trigger events inside the created object tagged with Card as you said. How would I go about this? I understand the flaw in my logic but what would be the best possible work for it.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer What makes you say that?

Comment: @Steve They are set to false in the update function, I changed it after you said so. I think Serlites answer was the most on point, if I put mousedown in update it seems to work. I still have no idea how to make it work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: as some people have pointed out in the comments, it may be (and probably is) the case that Update() is getting called before OnMouseDown(). I'm going to assume nothing else calls these functions, so it may be worth calling ZombieCards() from your OnMouseDown() event instead. That way you can be sure the sequence of events is right. (End edit)

Is there a reason you've set LeftChoice and RightChoice to public instead of private inside the class? This generally means something outside the class could be accessing it. Given you're using Update(), I assume you're inheriting from MonoBehaviour, which means you're attaching this script as a component to another GameObject. This means having private _leftChoice and private _rightChoice might be a better option here.

Another thing which may help - Random.Range(lowInt, hightInt) will return a random int between (and including) lowInt and (highInt - 1), so in your code it will never choose 5. I believe the intention is to start from index 0 and do something like this:

```
    private const bool NumChoices = 5;
    ...
    int randomNumberPicker = Random.Range(0, NumChoices);
    switch (randomNumberPicker)
    {
        case 0:
            ZombieCard1 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Frontcard1")) as GameObject;
            ZombieCard1.transform.Translate(0, -1, 0);
            if (leftChoice == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Jesus Marty! you fixed it! Great Scott!");
            }
            break;
        ...
    }
```

Of course, you could also just do Random.Range(1, 6)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I appreciate it, Ill try a switch rn.